# Jenkins - Git Publisher - Unable to push tags

Tags: git, jenkins

When using the Jenkins GIT Plugin "Git Publisher" to push a tag, I get the following error which doesn't give me any usable information that I can see. Has anyone faced a similar issue?

```
Pushing tag mytag to repo origin
RefSpec is "refs/tags/mytag:refs/heads/mytag".
Opening connection
Counting objects
Finding sources
Writing objects
ERROR: Failed to push tag mytag to origin
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: failed to write REJECTED_OTHER_REASON for 'refs/tags/mytag:refs/heads/mytag' refspec 'mytag' to https://<ADDRESSOFSTASH>/tomtest.git
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$9.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:1870)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitPublisher.perform(GitPublisher.java:306)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
        at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
        at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408)
Build step 'Git Publisher' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue when we upgraded the following plugins:

```
Git plugin       : from 2.4.0 to 2.4.4
Git client plugin: from 1.18.0 to 1.19.6
```

When we downgraded to the previous versions the issue was solved.

Comment: Thanks for that, filed an issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-37120

Answer (score 1):

Your Jenkins job tries to push report to Git repository with command like:

```
git push ssh://user@git.com/repositoryName tagName
```

Jenkins failed to do it because the tag already exists.

> ```
> ERROR: Failed to push tag tagName to repositoryName 
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git push ssh://user@git.com/repositoryName tagName" returned status code 1:
> stdout: 
>  ! [rejected] repositoryName -> tagName (already exists)
> ```

So, you just need to set forcing mode:
You have the configuration page for your job.

1. Please find 'Git Publisher' there.
2. **! Set 'Force Push' to the 'checked' state.**
3. Set 'Create new tag' and "Update new tag" to the 'checked' state.
4. Run this job again.

Answer (score 0):

In **Jenkins Job** to "**Create a New Tag** (or) **Update the Existing Tag** & Force Push"

The solution in Jenkins is in Git Publisher Plugin by,
Selection of **Create**+**Update**+**Force Push** into "***Checked***" status, as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]